# Distinguishing between different types of errors

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

My state looks like the following:

```
export interface SchemasState {
  list: Config6Schema[] | null;
  loading: boolean;
  error: string | null;
}
```

In my *fetching* thunk, I set `loading` to true when I send my API request, on success I set the `list` and on error I set the `error`. This works great.

Now I have a component, which looks at both `list` and `error`. When the `list` is present it renders the list. When the error is present, it shows an error instead.

However, when I coded the *addNewSchema* thunk, I am not sure how to handle the failure state of my API request, since if I set the error when my create API request fails, it would also affect the component showing the list. Whereas I just want to show maybe a modal incase it was the add request that failed.

Do I create separate error fields for all requests?

Component that triggers the add:

```
export interface AddSchemaPageProps {
  componentId: string;
}

const AddSchemaPage: NextPage<AddSchemaPageProps> = function ({
  componentId
}) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleSave = useCallback(
    async (data: Config6CreateSchemaDto) => {
      const schema = await dispatch(addSchema(componentId, data));

      if (schema) {
        Router.push(
          '/config/components/[componentId]/schemas/[schemaId]',
          `/config/components/${componentId}/schemas/${schema.id}`
        );
      }
    },
    [dispatch]
  );

  return (
    <Layout
      variant="config"
    >
      <h3>Add Schema</h3>
      <SchemaBuilder 
        onSave={handleSave}
      />
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you show us the component that's triggering the action?

Comment: Edit the question to show the component